# How to read attributes in a XML file using nodes in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, nodes

I am trying to read **ALL the Items** from this XML using nodes but I jus manage to return just very first one, or none with the following examples.

**How to read the entire list?**

***The file can contain hundreds of thousands.***

**XML file**

```
<data source="1" target="0">
  <list item_nb="1">
    <co id="1" constitution="20190612101007" item_nb="44046">
      <item cm="640001000101" obu="00007E" vc="2" vrn="SOLD" />
      <item cm="640001000101" obu="00009D" vc="6" vrn="04D11797" />
      <item cm="640001000101" obu="0000A3" vc="2" vrn="FAULTY" />
      <item cm="640001000101" obu="00018B" vc="2" vrn="07D54084" />
      <item cm="640001000101" obu="0001A6" vc="6" vrn="000422" />
      <item cm="640001000101" obu="0001B2" vc="2" vrn="90D24430" />
      <item cm="640001000101" obu="0001B3" vc="2" vrn="03LS1592" />
      <item cm="640001000101" obu="0001B9" vc="6" vrn="FAULTYJUNE15" />
       </co>
  </list>
</data>
```

**My Code in SQL**  (return only the first item)

```
declare @X xml;
select @X = T.MY_XML
from openrowset(bulk 'C:\XML\IEA.1.20190612101007-WL.XML', single_blob) as T(MY_XML)
select
   MY_XML.Item.value('(item/@cm)[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)'),
   MY_XML.Item.value('(item/@obu)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
   MY_XML.Item.value('(item/@vc)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
   MY_XML.Item.value('(item/@vrn)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)')
from @X.nodes('data/list/co') AS MY_XML (Item);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**found a way to work!**

```
declare @X xml;
select @X = T.MY_XML
from openrowset(bulk 'C:\XML\IEA.1.20190612101007-WL.XML', single_blob) as T(MY_XML)
select
   MY_XML.Item.value('(@cm)[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)'),
   MY_XML.Item.value('(@obu)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
   MY_XML.Item.value('(@vc)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
   MY_XML.Item.value('(@vrn)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)')
from @X.nodes('data/list/co/item') AS MY_XML (Item);
```

Comment: Great, that you found your own solution! Just a tiny hint: You can address an attribute with a simple `@cm`, no need for `(@cm)[1]`, as an attribute is a singleton by definition. And it might be better to use `SINGLE_CLOB` instead of `SINGLE_BLOB`, as you are reading a **C**haracter-blob.